# Swift - Inheriting UIViewController from a generic base class that is also a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, oop, generics, inheritance

So I have a base class, `DataViewController<T>`, which inherits from `UITableViewController` as follows:

```
class DataTableViewController<T : BMPage<BMData>> : UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    // implementations...
}
```

I also have a `TournamentsViewController` which inherits from `DataViewController` with the generics passed in:

```
class TournamentsViewController: DataTableViewController<TournamentPage> {
    // overrides, etc.
}
```

For reference, here are `BMPage<T>`:

```
open class BMPage<T : Codable> : Decodable {

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    var data : [T]

    required public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let vals = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try vals.decode([T].self, forKey: .data)
    }
}

extension BMPage: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(data, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

... and `BMData`:

```
open class BMData : Codable {

    public enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    required public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let vals = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try vals.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try vals.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve: various `UITableViewController` subclasses that just need to specify generics in order to specify their specific data. Here are my Tournament and TournamentPage implementations which should better explain this concept:

```
open class Tournament : BMData {
    let game_id: Int = 0
    let game_iteration_id: Int = 0
    let state: Int = 0
    let starts_at: String = ""
    let creator_id: Int = 0
    let stream_url: String? = nil
    let entrant_count: Int = 0
    let prereg_count: Int = 0
    let path: String = ""
}

open class TournamentPage : BMPage<BMData> {
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "tournaments"
    }

    let page: String? = nil
    let results_per_page: String = ""
    let tournament_count: Int = 0
}
```

The problem: the compiler doesn't like that I'm doing this as it's throwing multiple, yet very similar errors such as:

- `Cannot convert return expression of type 'TournamentsViewController'
  to return type 'UIViewController'`
- `Cannot convert return expression of type
  'TournamentsViewController?' to return type 'UIViewController?'`

Here is an example of such an expression (taken from the default `ModelController` that XCode threw in there, which is where all of these errors occur:

```
    let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataViewController") as! TournamentsViewController
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do? I'll admit, I am new to Swift (only started learning it this week), so maybe I'm completely misunderstanding typical Swift practices and just what it was designed to do, but achieving this in a language such as C# (and probably even Objective-C, though I'm a bit rusty on it as it's been a while since I've last used it) is pretty much what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to instantiate view controller like this?
`let viewController = MyTableViewController()`
Than `navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}`